# Are cell and cons cell the same in Common Lisp? And how does one access a content of a cell?

Tags: common-lisp

I am new to programming and CL. I am trying to understand the concept of cell. I sometimes see these two terms used in SO questions and elsewhere: cell, and cons cell. Are they one and the same thing? Or are they different?

Someone asked me to grasp cell as pointer (in C), but being C-ignorant, I faced two problems instead of one. Understanding pointers and then understanding cell.

So my question is: Is cell some kind of container? Is it possible to name an empty container and then put some (a new) value in it? And if yes, are nil and '() treated same or differently?

For example:

```
(defvar *empty-cell-1* nil)
(defvar *empty-cell-2* '())
```

And now assignments:

```
(defvar *first-cell* *empty-cell-1*)
(defvar *second-cell* *empty-cell-2*)
```

Now I try to assign a value to the two

```
(setf *first-cell* 0)
(setf *second-cell* 0)
```

If I understand correctly, both the cell-names get the same value. But then, is there a way to put something as "content" in a cell? Something like, which will make *second-cell* something like '(0) without using the list statement? Or is a single element list equivalent to single cell (as container) with its content (as assigned value)?

My fundamental confusion is, how to distinguish container from content of a cell, not list. Or is my approach to understanding cell not appropriate for common-lisp?

Comment: From the answer assigned by SO what I understand is that when people refer to a cell, it always means cons cell, and cons cell always has two contents car and cdr. If this understanding is inaccurate, please do clarify.

Comment: This also means that I could do the following. (defvar *my-cell* nil). And then (setf (car *my-cell*) "car") and (setf (cdr *my-cell*) "cdr"). Is my understanding correct?